# Setting a folder size limit on Windows Server 2003 - is it possible?

Tags: size, directory, limit, windows-server-2003

I have a shared webhosting server at home based on Apache, MySQL, hMailServer, etc. Is it possible to limit my users' htdocs directory to a certain no. of GB?
If it is, how do I achieve that?
Thank you!